# Why does hamcrest say that a byte 0 is not equal to an int 0?

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

Consider the following test case using standard `JUnit` asserts and hamcrest's `assertThat`:

```
byte b = 0;
int i = 0;

assertEquals(b, i); // success
assertThat(b, equalTo(i)); // java.lang.AssertionError: Expected: <0> but: was <0>

if (b == i) {
    fail(); // test fails, so b == i is true for the JVM
}
```

Why is that so? The values are apparently equal for the JVM because `b == i` is `true`, so why does `hamcrest` fail?

Comment: Because `Byte.valueOf((byte) 0).equals(Integer.valueOf(0))` is false.

Comment: As seen in *assylias*' example above, the byte gets auto-boxed into a Byte-object. As seen in the [Hamcrest's equalTo docs](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/core/IsEqual.html#equalTo(T)) it uses the Object1.equals(Object2). Since both the byte and int are primitives, it auto-boxes them to Byte and Integer objects. Byte1.equals(Integer1) will return false, even though the values of these boxed object are the same.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`Assert#assertThat`](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Assert.html#assertThat%28T,%20org.hamcrest.Matcher%29) is a generic method. Primitive types don't work with generics. In this case, the `byte` and `int` are boxed to `Byte` and `Integer`, respectively.

It then becomes (within `assertThat`)

```
Byte b = 0;
Integer i = 0;

b.equals(i);
```

[`Byte#equals(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html#equals-java.lang.Object-)'s implementation checks if the argument is of type `Byte`, returning `false` immediately if it isn't.

On the other hand, `assertEquals` is [`Assert#assertEquals(long, long)`](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28long,%20long%29) in which case both the `byte` and `int` arguments are promoted to `long` values. Internally, this uses `==` on two primitive `long` values which are equal.

---

Note that this boxing conversion works because `assertThat` is declared as

```
public static <T> void assertThat(T actual, Matcher<? super T> matcher) {
```

where the `byte` is boxed to a `Byte` for `T`, and the `int` is a boxed to an `Integer` (within the call to `equalTo`), but inferred as a `Number` to match the `Matcher<? super T>`.

This works with Java 8's improved generic inference. You'd need explicit type arguments to make it work in Java 7.

Answer (score 13):

This happens because the `int` and `byte` are boxed to `Integer` and `Byte` as hamcrest matchers operate on objects, not on primitives. So you are comparing an `Integer` with a `Byte`, and the implementation of `Byte.equals()` is:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Byte) {
        return value == ((Byte)obj).byteValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

and `Integer.equals()`:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Integer) {
        return value == ((Integer)obj).intValue();
    }
    return false;
}
```

In other words, an `Integer` and `Byte` are always unequal. When comparing primitives, just use `Assert.assertEquals` instead. The hamcrest matchers are powerful, but mostly intended for (complex) object assertions.

Comment: Is there any reason for Java to not check for values in the same range? E.g. `if (obj instanceof Integer) { return ((Integer)obj).intValue() == (int) value;}` in `Byte.equals()`?

Comment: @sina Well, that's probably the reason we have primitives we can use instead. When Java compares two objects, it first checks if both objects are of the same type; if not, it simply returns false. `Integer` and `Byte` are objects, so the same applies to them. If `(new Byte(0)).equals(new Integer(0))` would return true it would be a bit strange to me. A comparable example would be if `(new Dog("Luke")).equals(new Cat("Luke"))` would return true, simply because they have the same name (I know, not the best example here, but then you see how strange it looks if it would return true).

Comment: @KevinCruijssen It is a thing that you don't expect when boxing happens. One could argue that `Number` could require an equals that does allow `Integer` and `Byte` to be comparable, but that would probably again lead to unexpected behavior with `Float` and `Double` or very complex implementation to take into account 'other' number types.